# Cannot Boot After 15.10 Upgrade [AMD graphics driver problems]

Tags: boot, fsck, 15.10

I'm in desperation mode. I upgraded to 15.10 last night, via `sudo do-release-upgrade`. I did nothing else at the time. It passed without incident.

Then it asked to restart. I pressed Enter. It rebooted, went to the Ubuntu load screen, and hangs.

I pressed Ctrl+Meta+F2 to view the command line. It says...

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean, 995697/3871592 files, 52624527/154846720 blocks
```

...and stays there forever. I can get to recovery mode, but none of the options help (I ran them all). I can get to root terminal, but I don't know what to do from there.

I have backups, but I also don't want to spend a week setting up my system all over again.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be related to [Bug #1493888](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1493888). I use `fglrx` as my graphics driver, and according to the [offical Changelog](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) for Wily Werewolf, that is not compatible at this time.

<s>There are workarounds in the comments of the bug on Launchpad, but it did not work for me personally. I will be downgrading for the time being.</s>

---

**UPDATE:** I'm now working just fine on Ubuntu 15.10. Apparently, `fglrx` [will not be supported in Ubuntu 16.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04), so moving away from that proprietary driver is ideal if at all possible.

> **WARNING:** Before you start in on all this jazz, make sure your graphics card actually *is* supported by `xserver-xorg-video-ati`. To
>   find your graphics card model, run...
>
> $ lspci -nn | grep VGA
>
> Your model is towards the end of the line. Then, check [the list on
>   the official Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) for your model. You may need to ignore
>   the letter at the end of the model; mine was a `Radeon HD 6520G`, but
>   I had to search the page for only `6520`.

The lack of screen resolution options on the open source `xserver-xorg-video-ati` driver stems from the fact that, if `fglrx` is present on the system at all, it will *massively* interfere with `xserver-xorg-video-ati`.

If anyone else hits this problem, you can [purge fglrx](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx) from TTY or recovery mode root. Then, reinstall the open-source drivers.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver xorg-core
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot your computer, and you'll find that the problem has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a solution yet, but I do have a workaround: If you can access the GRUB menu, select the "Advanced Boot Options", and select your linux kernel in Upstart mode.

Comment: I remember trying this before I downgraded back to 15.04. It did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the GNU GRUB screen, choose *Advanced options for Ubuntu*. Then choose the option *Ubuntu, with Linux 4.xx-xx-generic (Upstart)*. There attempted to enter Ubuntu, and then displayed options, you press I to repair the system.

Ubuntu will start now without errors of `fsck` from util-linux 2.26.2.

Comment: ¡Hola, Fernando! Bienvenido a AskUbuntu. Esto sitio es solamente en ingles. Por favor, escribio en ingles aqui. Tu ingles no necesita ser perfecto (puedes ver mi español es...asi asi). :) También, esta espacio es por respuestas. Si tiene una pregunta, creas una preguna nueva. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score -1):

you should reinstall your desktop. 
prees ctrl+alt+f1 or some Fi (i<7)

login with your user and pass.

if you use uinty write here :

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

if use Gnome :

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

Also, see this bug report that solve problem by upgrading :

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/552018

Comment: Nope. The graphics driver was broken (fglrx)

Comment: I had this problem on my Laptop too and I fix it with this !!